# Check if PAGEUP or PAGEDOWN is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a windows-form application, with pages in it.

Short and simple question;

How to I check wether the Page-UP or Page-Down key is pressed when in the windows-form?

The purpose of this is, so that I can go through the pages by clicking one of those 2 buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your form. And add form key down event handler:

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
      //do something on page up
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown)
      //do something on page down
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should override `ProcessCmdKey` method

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.PageUp) {
            MessageBox.Show("Pressed PageUp");
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == Keys.PageDown) {
            MessageBox.Show("Pressed PageDown");
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```